# Is Camel Case notation required for the Asset Name of an NFT?

Tags: nft, metadata

Hello i just have noticed that i can mint NFTs with the Cardano serialization Lib with out using Camel Case notation: I can have string spaces as well a special characters.

I have read in the CIP-25 nothing that does not let me do that

https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/

But using Cardano-Cli I see it is not posible. Anybody knows anything about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any limitations are artificial limitations in conversion. On the blockchain it's all hex and current master branch of node the CLI expects all inputs to be hex which should remove the limitation entirely.

Comment: I aks because i minted some NFTs  and CardanoScan does not show me the human readable Name